# How can I get this svg circle to appear above my d3 path and not below?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I wrote a d3 graph plugin that draws a graph based on real time data given to it. When you mouseover the graph, there is a tooltip that follows your mouse, showing data at that point. Part of this tooltip is a circle that appears on the path at the closest point to the cursor. The problem is that no matter what I try, I cannot get this circle to appear above the path line like it's suposed to. I have tried using z-index, changing the append order of elements, and some other really wacky attempts. Nothing has had an affect (besides breaking everything.) Here's a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/WfvfpJgf) of the code. The element in question has the class "focusCircle". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried appending a second `g` element to the SVG that contains only the circle?

Comment: Well I appended it like this. `rrd3.graph.append("g").append("circle")` but that didn't seem to help.

Comment: Well SVG elements are rendered in the order in which they appear, so there must be a mistake somewhere when you tried to change that.

Comment: Can you show me the correct change I should make?

Comment: I would append a separate `g` element after the top level `g` element and add the circle to that (and only the circle).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you show me where and what you would put? Sorry if that's asking too much.

Comment: Like here http://jsfiddle.net/pj2dgr6j/

Comment: Do you still have the issue? I had the same question (I think) and got it resolved, luckily. It's all about when/how/where the stuff in the DOM is put. A bit annoying how simple yet confusing it can get. See the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35078205/path-in-svg-placed-in-front-of-the-circles-in-d3-chart-despite-the-order-of-app#35078418).

Answer (score 0):

Your circle gets rendered before the "resize" function is called. The "resize" function calls the "draw" function, where 2 paths get appended. I think those are the ones above your circle.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. But even after changing the order of appends, it didn't fix it. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Could I see your updated code? Maybe a plnkr or jsbin or jsfiddle would be useful