# Path in SVG placed in front of the circles in D3 chart, despite the order of append

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, charts

My data line is supposed to be put **behind** the circles but refuses stubbornly to do so. First I thought it had to do with the order of appending but, apparently, it doesn't. And I've learned that [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29282120/how-can-i-get-this-svg-circle-to-appear-above-my-d3-path-and-not-below) had a similar issue too. I'd like the dots to look like [this picture](http://www.clipular.com/c/5787996821913600.png?k=5XLH2JZGPdTdeICEfnI2vUm0pnc).

I've noticed that **the last circle** actually behaves as expected. It gets behind the line if I append the set of circles first and it gets in front in the opposite case. But all the other data points don't obey the same logic.

Generally, I'll be creating charts with more than a single data point, so it's going to be a problem...

What am I missing in [my chart](https://jsfiddle.net/Chamster/0yxo1wyz/)?

```
gees.append("path")
  .attr("d", d3.svg.line().x(posX).y(posY)(data));
gees.append("circle")
  .attr({ cx: posX, cy: posY, r: dotSize });
```

As a **secondary** question, as I'm starting with D3 just now, I'll gladly accept comments on my approach of data binding and structuring the element creation and manipulation, should a viewer recognize some code smell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that when you do:

```
// Set of g elements in for the individual data points
var gees = graph1.selectAll("g").data(data).enter().append("g");

// Path appended BEFORE the circles
gees.append("path")
  .attr("d", d3.svg.line().x(posX).y(posY)(data))
  .attr("class","dataPath");
```

You are making as many paths as their are data.

**Example**: if data has length 10 you are drawing 10 paths!. So every time a new path is drawn over the other.
This is however correct when you making circles, array of length 10 so 10 circles.

So the correct way is like this:

```
//this will make a single path
graph1.append("path")
  .attr("d", d3.svg.line().x(posX).y(posY)(data))
  .attr("class","dataPath");
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/ydazL6o5/)

**EDIT**

If you see your DOM

```
<g>
   <path d="M10,395L30,346.23626273003947L50,348.88315845093945L70,325.8408757172729L90,361.79282401218563L110,337.23829975521113L130,271.36254043537434L150,326.84355151115744L170,296.18083274584734L190,239.00309425733596L210,246.4312641551351L229.99999999999997,261.73836974728044L250,222.77033711908345L270,175.77553751327844L290,202.07665355388494L310,162.47810406521793L330,161.2957419597571L350,131.1359499531521L370,129.23952903887664L390,139.51540231604645L410,144.10064067915437L430,126.07475247355066L449.99999999999994,114.16957928889813L470.00000000000006,47.3902223639799L490,67.03516083686108L510,10.340972431627879L530,5L550,27.22071082134911L570,52.42233413128351L590,17.020429086361613" class="dataPath"></path>
   <circle cx="10" cy="395" r="5" class="dataPoint"></circle>
   <line x1="10" y1="246.0618379173906" x2="10" y2="241.0618379173906" stroke="lightgrey" stroke-width="1"></line>
   <line x1="0" y1="246.0618379173906" x2="600" y2="246.0618379173906" class="axis"></line>
</g>
```

Then next DOM a new circle but old path:

```
<g>
   <path d="M10,395L30,346.23626273003947L50,348.88315845093945L70,325.8408757172729L90,361.79282401218563L110,337.23829975521113L130,271.36254043537434L150,326.84355151115744L170,296.18083274584734L190,239.00309425733596L210,246.4312641551351L229.99999999999997,261.73836974728044L250,222.77033711908345L270,175.77553751327844L290,202.07665355388494L310,162.47810406521793L330,161.2957419597571L350,131.1359499531521L370,129.23952903887664L390,139.51540231604645L410,144.10064067915437L430,126.07475247355066L449.99999999999994,114.16957928889813L470.00000000000006,47.3902223639799L490,67.03516083686108L510,10.340972431627879L530,5L550,27.22071082134911L570,52.42233413128351L590,17.020429086361613" class="dataPath"></path>
   <circle cx="30" cy="346.23626273003947" r="5" class="dataPoint"></circle>
   <line x1="30" y1="246.0618379173906" x2="30" y2="241.0618379173906" stroke="lightgrey" stroke-width="1"></line>
   <line x1="0" y1="246.0618379173906" x2="600" y2="246.0618379173906" class="axis"></line>
</g>
```

So you are making new groups and in that the circle and path DOM is getting added.

I think if you inspect your DOM you will understand the problem better.

In my fiddle the line is behind the circles the last one appears in front the reason is the line is only till the center of the last circle.

**EDIT AGAIN**

To make the circle above the line like [this](http://www.clipular.com/c/5787996821913600.png?k=5XLH2JZGPdTdeICEfnI2vUm0pnc)

```
//make the path first
graph1.append("path")
  .attr("d", d3.svg.line().x(posX).y(posY)(data))
  .attr("class","dataPath");

//make the group
// Set of g elements in for the individual data points
var gees = graph1.selectAll("g").data(data).enter().append("g");
//add the circle to the group    
// Path appended BEFORE the circles
// Circles appended AFTER the path
gees.append("circle")
  .attr({ cx: posX, cy: posY, r: dotSize })
  .attr("class", "dataPoint");
```

Working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/ydazL6o5/1/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: It helps but I'm still confused, although less now. I missed totally that I'm creating a bunch of paths all over the others. Now, that I do, I still don't get it - even if I have 30 paths, whose are rendered **before** the circles, so independent of the number of unnecessary paths, those should still be **behind** the circles. Or is it because of me placing those suckers in separate g elements?

Comment: yeah i can see all the circles behind the line see wat i see here http://www.clipular.com/c/6058246096289792.png?k=piLXYpjVx-iyJ9GmsiccXoAggm8

Comment: Awesome website! Here's [what I'm trying to get](http://www.clipular.com/c/5787996821913600.png?k=5XLH2JZGPdTdeICEfnI2vUm0pnc). I see in the dome that my g's are placed before the path. So the question is how to change the order of appending... It seems not to do what I expect it to, even in your fiddle. How do we push in the path so it gets first in the svg? Or at least before the gees?